# Parse Nonstandard API Response into an Array

Tags: php

I have a query that gets data from an API, this is an example of what it returns.

```
testuser=bandwidth=36.4/128000&domain=test.com&email=test@user.com&inodes=1566
testuser=bandwidth=36.4/128000&domain=test.com&email=test@user.com&inodes=1566
testuser=bandwidth=36.4/128000&domain=test.com&email=test@user.com&inodes=1566
```

I want to convert this into some form of a usable array, pass it into a view as a table.

What is confusing me more is that the user name at the start is just the username, no key, just the value of username. Not sure how to convert this to an array and then loop through to output it.

This is the first two lines of raw output from the API return.

user1=bandwidth=7.05 / 128000&creator=mtemtfqx&date_created=1582530762&default=domain1.com&email_daily_limit=1000&email_deliveries_outgoing=0&inode=1492 / unlimited&ip=139.99.69.103&ips=139.99.69.103
&list=domain1.com
&package=shared5"a=32.2 / 5120&suspended=No&type=user&vdomains=1 / 5 user2=bandwidth=1.46 / 128000&creator=mtemtfqx&date_created=1583765836&default=domain2.net&email_daily_limit=1000&email_deliveries_outgoing=1&inode=2355 / unlimited&ip=139.99.69.103&ips=139.99.69.103
&list=domain2.net

Comment: Have you _tried_ to parse the sting? Your example data is well formed, just not using any discernible public standard.

Comment: there is a problem in your data, testuser=bandwidth= , missing & before bandwidth., but this is a serialize form of data, or string, which you can parse to array using parse_str

Comment: I thought it was missing an & before bandwidth but the provider of the API advises that it is correct.  Will look at parse_str, but I suspect it won't work as testuser is the value with no key.

Comment: "the provider of the API advises that it is correct"...ok so what PHP data structure do you want to get from that? Is it two variables (`testuser` and `bandwith`) being assigned the same value, or is `testuser=bandwidth`the name of a single variable, or what? It's unclear. No-one can give you any detailed help unless you explain all the rules which govern this data format (which the API provider should be able to tell you), and/or show what array structure you're trying to achieve. (P.S. it looks a bit like the querystring data you get in a URL, but it's not precisely the same format).

Comment: testuser represents the name of the user, everything else that follows are the variables returned from the API related to that user.  So each line represent a single user with all the related items relating to my domains.  The provider suggests that I should loop through pulling out the username from each line with strok and the data with strstr.

Comment: @Holo Do you get this entire thing as a string or you have added it line by line just to demonstrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This splits the input string by an `=`, but only 2 parts, the first part is the user, the second part are the values.  Then using `parse_str()` it decodes the values.

These are put into an array with the user name as the key...

```
$output = [];
$data = 'testuser=bandwidth=36.4/128000&domain=test.com&email=test@user.com&inodes=1566
testuser1=bandwidth=36.41/128000&domain=test.com&email=test@user.com&inodes=1566
testuser2=bandwidth=36.42/128000&domain=test.com&email=test@user.com&inodes=1566';

foreach ( explode(PHP_EOL, $data ) as $line )   {
    $lineData = explode("=", $line, 2);
    if ( isset($lineData[1]) )  {
        parse_str($lineData[1], $userData );
        $output [ $lineData[0] ] = $userData;
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

gives the output of...

```
Array
(
    [testuser] => Array
        (
            [bandwidth] => 36.4/128000
            [domain] => test.com
            [email] => test@user.com
            [inodes] => 1566
        )

    [testuser1] => Array
        (
            [bandwidth] => 36.41/128000
            [domain] => test.com
            [email] => test@user.com
            [inodes] => 1566
        )

    [testuser2] => Array
        (
            [bandwidth] => 36.42/128000
            [domain] => test.com
            [email] => test@user.com
            [inodes] => 1566
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel, I understand what you have done there and it makes sense, the issue is that the API returns the data together, not individual lines.  There is a \n that separates each record so I guess I would first need to explode by \n then try and process each row?

Comment: I've updated the code, it just splits the data by lines.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that although it returns Undefined offset:1 at the first line within the foreach.

Comment: Does that happen with the example code or just your real data?

Comment: Ah, the real data.

Comment: Is it possible to show the first 2 lines of this data (in the question preferably)

Comment: Nigel, I have added the first two lines as it is returned from the API in the Question.

Comment: Code now checks if there are 2 elements in each row

Comment: Nigel, amazing, works perfectly now.  Apologies for taking up your time.  I really appreciate it.  I should probably avoid doing complicated tasks like this.  Not complicated for you I suspect but I am nearly 60, not a programmer, just trying to make my site work the way I want it to and display my own personal hosting accounts.